# FormBuilder 2 - Notification email to the form submitter

Tags: plugins, form

I have been using the [FormBuilder2](https://github.com/roundhouse/FormBuilder-2-Craft-CMS) plugin and it's fantastic. I am trying to understand if there is anyway that I can send an automatic email to the form submitter using this plugin. There is a possibility to insert a fixed email address in the plugin setting but this, of course, doesn't answer my need.

Any help would be appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the also wonderful [amforms](https://github.com/am-impact/amforms), which has this standard built in. The only thing is that it will send an exact copy of the admin mail. If you need a custom submitter mail, my guess is that sproutforms + sprout email is the best solution (you'll need them both).

Comment: Thanks! It is indeed a great plugin. I didn't figure how to customize the body of the notification email. Now it sends automatically the info that have been submitted. Do you have any experience with that?

Comment: Like Ben says, you could use it with Sprout email, easiest would then be to combine it with Sprout Forms. If you want a custom submitter mail voor amforms or formbuilder, you'd need to dive into the plugin. I've build a 'ContactFromSendCopy' plugin based on the standard contactform "onBeforeSendEmail' event. So it is possible, but you need to know what you're doing ( I had to hire a developer to finish it correctly)

Comment: If you are using amforms, make sure you copy the template `craft/plugins/amforms/templates/_display/templates/email.twig` into your templates directory and reference that in the plugin / form settings.

Answer (score 1):

Sprout Email is designed to be extensible by other plugins. One reason we have kept it separate from Sprout Forms is so that users could have the option to manage all of their email in one place, regardless of which plugins they need to manage email for.

Plugin developers can extend their plugins to support Sprout Email, additionally, you can write your own custom plugin to add support for another plugin too.  For example, Sprout Email extends itself in this way to add support for several Craft Events. (You can see these examples in the `sproutforms/integrations` folder.)

It looks like FormBuilder2 has an `onBeforeSave` Event that you could write a [Sprout Email Custom Event](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email/docs/notifications/custom-events) to support.

Depending on your coding skills or preferences, that might not be ideal, so it may be worth petitioning FormBuilder2 to add support for Sprout Email itself or add an `onSave` event that would ensure your Form Entry was saved before triggering any email. This could at least give you complete control over your email in the short run until FormBuilder2 added additional support for what you need down the road, or it could give you a way to manage your email notification needs all in one place.